# Include images added to 3d model when exporting to glTF, OBJ, or DAE

Tags: gltf

I have imported a 3D model into Blender, and then used Add Images to place a number of png files inside the model. When I export to glTF, I am not able to view the images within the model.

Answer (score 0):

The glTF Blender addon supports meshes with textures, but I'm not sure about standalone image imports... You'll probably need to create planes and add your images to them. For best results, see the guidelines in https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html.